# EfCachingProvider and DbContext

Tags: caching, entity-framework-4, dbcontext

I have trying to find the way to use EFCachingProvider from  [Tracing and Caching Provider Wrappers for Entity Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32) with Entity Framework and DbContext. I use EF 4.x DbContext Generator for c# to generate model classes.
I've already added references to EFProviderWrapperToolkit, EFCachingProvider, EFTracingProvider. I also made changes in my web.config file to :

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="Server=myServer;Database=MyDB;User ID=User;Password=pass;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="EFTracingProvider" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="EF Caching Data Provider" invariant="EFCachingProvider" description="Caching Provider Wrapper" type="EFCachingProvider.EFCachingProviderFactory, EFCachingProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=def642f226e0e59b" />
      <add name="EF Tracing Data Provider" invariant="EFTracingProvider" description="Tracing Provider Wrapper" type="EFTracingProvider.EFTracingProviderFactory, EFTracingProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=def642f226e0e59b" />
      <add name="EF Generic Provider Wrapper" invariant="EFProviderWrapper" description="Generic Provider Wrapper" type="EFProviderWrapperToolkit.EFProviderWrapperFactory, EFProviderWrapperToolkit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=def642f226e0e59b" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

But when app start, it throws an error in DbConnectionWrapper from EFProviderWrapperToolkit
in line:

```
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerInvariantName);
```

This is class which inherits from DbContext:

```
public class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyEntities()
        : base("MyEntities")
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("Product");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductPhoto>().ToTable("ProductPhoto");


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductPhoto> ProductPhoto { get; set; }
}
```

I've already read post: [USING TRACING AND CACHING PROVIDER WRAPPERS WITH CODEFIRST](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/03/31/using-tracing-and-caching-provider-wrappers-with-codefirst/), but it didn't solve my problem.

Does anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: Always tell which error.

Answer (score 3):

We have used the EFCachingProvider with Entity Framework and and Code First. You can see our implementation in our source code for [MVCForum on CodePlex](http://themvcforum.codeplex.com/).

We found that there were many examples that showed the tracing provider but nothing that showed the caching provider with Code First.

It didn't just work with our code out of the box. We had a problem using `DbContext` and `TransactionScope`. In order to make calls that were overridden in the `EFCachingProvider` wrapper, and thereby redirected to the cache, we needed to use transactions from the connection, rather than `TransactionScope`. We couldn't get to the connection from our `DbContext` because it handles the connection itself, so we used the underlying `ObjectContext`.

```
        private readonly IDbTransaction _transaction;
```

etc

```
        _objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter) _context).ObjectContext;
        if (_objectContext.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            _objectContext.Connection.Open();
            _transaction = _objectContext.Connection.BeginTransaction();
        }
```

The caching provider then intercepts calls appropriately. We use the `_transaction`object to issue `Commit()` or `Rollback` etc.

You can see the full implementation in our UnitOfWork class.

Comment: Is it safe to put the _transaction.Commit() inside this class' Dispose() method?

Comment: Joset, I would not recommend that. You should control commit and rollback explicitly, as we do in MVCForum.